# ST & VIM -- no colors

Tags: vim, x-st

I figured out there is some sort of a bug with Suckless's [ST terminal emulator](https://st.suckless.org/) (0.8.2) regarding VIM. If I download ST's source files and open a configuration file `config.h` I can find a setting:

```
char *termname = "st-256color";
```

I keep this default setting and build the ST binary. Then I start the built ST binary and I noticed this:

- keys <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>HOME</kbd> work fine inside the ST terminal,
- VIM if executed from within ST terminal will display no syntax highlighting.

---

On the other hand, if I change the default setting to:

```
char *termname = "xterm-color";
```

I notice this:

- keys <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>HOME</kbd> do not work inside ST terminal - they both print tilde `~`
- VIM if executed from within ST terminal will display proper syntax highlighting.

---

In both cases I had a file `~/.inputrc` with only one line:

```
set enable-keypad on
```

Which was supposed to make <kbd>DEL</kbd> work accordingly to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/St#Troubleshooting). But if I remove it in the second case, keys <kbd>DEL</kbd> and <kbd>HOME</kbd> work, but <kbd>DEL</kbd> does not.

So it is like I can't have it all. One or the other... Does anyone have any ideas, how to overcome this? I would perfer a solution without `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: I found out that if I put `tput smkx` command in `.bashrc` **DEL** works and I can remove `.inputrc`. But this is not the solution that I want. Does anyone know if there is a fix that I can do in source code to make **DEL** work.

Comment: I also found out that in my previous comment I was wrong! `tput smkx` makes **DEL** work only until I use `vim` for the first time and then it *DEL* stops working again... That is until I enter `tput smkx` in the terminal again. And then it works again... So `vim` changes something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this setting in my `~/.vimrc` and with the term name as `st-256color`, and colors just work fine.

Add this before you set the colorscheme:

```
" set Vim-specific sequences for RGB colors
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
```

Source: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/993#issuecomment-255651605

I cannot tell for the home button now, as I don't have my arch machine with me right now, but del surely works for me with the above setting.

Comment: Your answer was a crutial part of the solution. Key here was to (a) use `char *termname = "st-256color";` in the source code to get a proper `TERM=st-256color` enviromental variable *(at this point colors inside `vim` and keyboard keys don't work)*. (b) Then I used your solution which made sure that I got colors inside `vim`. (c) At the end I made sure that all the keys are working by putting `set enable-keypad on
` inside `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: Well it looks like this is not yet solved! To rely on a `~/.inputrc` was not a good idea, because this script is only executed on my local machine! If I open ST and within execute SSH to connect to a remote computer, *keyboard keys* stop working (!) because `~/.inputrc` is not present on the remote computer... So I need a better solution...